# Event.preventdefault() after async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, event-listener, preventdefault

In order to prevent bs-stepper from going to the next step, I'm using this eventhandler approach. Unfortunatley this approach seems not working with an async function like isFaceValid()...
Both version below are not working. No matter if I use async key word or not.

Is it even possible what I'm trying to achieve?

At the moment I assume I have to stick with this event handler approach, I don't see an other way to work with bs-stepper https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-stepper

```
stepperFormEl.addEventListener('show.bs-stepper', function(event) {
    form.classList.remove('was-validated')
    var nextStep = event.detail.indexStep
    var currentStep = nextStep

    if (currentStep > 0) {
        currentStep--
    }

    var stepperPan = stepperPanList[currentStep]

    if ((stepperPan.getAttribute('id') === 'test-form-1' && (!$('#inputUserImage').get(0).files.length)) ||
        (stepperPan.getAttribute('id') === 'test-form-1' && !anAsyncFunction())) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }
})


stepperFormEl.addEventListener('show.bs-stepper', async function(event) {
    form.classList.remove('was-validated')
    var nextStep = event.detail.indexStep
    var currentStep = nextStep

    if (currentStep > 0) {
        currentStep--
    }

    var stepperPan = stepperPanList[currentStep]

    if ((stepperPan.getAttribute('id') === 'test-form-1' && (!$('#inputUserImage').get(0).files.length)) ||
        (stepperPan.getAttribute('id') === 'test-form-1' && !await anAsyncFunction())) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }
})
```

Comment: And what is `isFaceValid()`

Comment: its just an async function which return true or false. but because its async the return value is returned always to late.

Comment: The problem that synchronious code is executed is always before any async code. You need to dig into the bs-stepper inside. If it can accept Promise that will help you then, if not then monkeypatching it to support Promise in the result

Comment: just comment everything and try Event.preventDefault independently . if it works comment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using the event handler approach, bs-stepper comes from with various available public methods, such as "next" or "previous". See: https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-stepper#next

So you can do something like

```
if (!await anAsyncFunction()) {
  return;
}

bsStepper.next();
```

like that you'll be able to prevent showing the next step

Answer (score 0):

By adapting the user workflow I was able to keep the eventhandler code synchronous. Problem solved :)